# Jest: Expect getByRole element to be missing, but the test fails with TestingLibraryElementError

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a test where I use `getByRole` to verify that an element exists in the page. However, I have another test where I expect the element to be missing. I thought this would be pretty straightforward using the `.not` syntax, but when I try I get an error.

Things I've tried:

```
expect(getByRole('timestamp')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
expect(getByRole('timestamp')).toBeNull;
expect(getByRole('timestamp')).toThrowError();
... and more...
```

The error I get:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "timestamp"
```

How can I verify that an element with a given role isn't present in the document?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [this blog post](https://vijayt.com/post/functional-testing-using-react-testing-library-and-jest/), I found out that you can use `queryByRole` instead of `getByRole` to test for cases where you expect the element to be missing.

The final version looks like this:

```
expect(queryByRole('timestamp')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
```

Comment: Yes! And you can check more in the official [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet#queries).